# How to send a caption for the each image in jQuery File Upload

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using jQuery File Upload for My Rails Application to upload multiple files using browse button and drag-n-drop.Below is the link for the demo site

http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

When i Add 3 files and click on the Start Upload the form get submitted 3 times, and i get file object one by one i.e one for each submission.

I need some changes like need a caption text field with each of the the image and should save the Caption for that particular Image.

Suppose i set name of text field as `'caption'` it is sending the value of the third `'caption'` in each form submission.

And when i set name of text field as `'caption[]'` it is sending the value of the all the three `'captions'` in each form submission but i am not able to pick which image has which caption.

I am facing the problem as i am very new to jQuery & HTML-5. Is there any work around for this issue?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could you prefix the file name to the caption with a delimiter like `#` or `;`?  Like, `File_Name#Caption`, maybe

Comment: I also try the same but it fails when we select the same file again or select 2 files with same filename.

Comment: You can try appending a time stamp or any unique identifier on the server side..

Comment: but problem remain same as i can't identify on server side which unique id belongs to which image

Comment: Can someone please answer this? There's [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325549/how-to-include-pic-caption-while-saving-images-using-bootstrap-jquery-image-uplo) that's blatantly a duplicate but it can't be marked as such until this has been answered.